# How iOS app can get particular product information Using iBeacon

Tags: ios, iphone

I am going to integrate EstimoteSDk in my existing iOS App and i understand the integration process but i have a small doubt that how app get notification of particular product like name , price and discount of the product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only information contained in an iBeacon advertising packet is the region UUID (which on iOS you have to already know to scan for it), and the major and minor numbers which are often treated together as an identifier for a particular beacon within the set of beacons designated by the UUID, and the effective transmit power level (used as an input to the receiver's ranging algorithm).

To turn this back into a product on a shelf, you would have to associate the beacon identifier number with some other source of information about what product it is located near, most likely by having your application query a server on which you maintain a database of what product or promotion should be associated with each beacon identifier.

Comment: ..Sorry for the late response.Thanks for your reply and  i also want to know iBeacon exact distance from the Smart phone like 10 meters, 15 meters etc....

Comment: I know we can get relative distance from the iBeacon using proximity like "Unknown","Immediate","Near" and "Far" states but i want exact distance in meters is it possible?

Comment: You can get a numeric distance, but accuracy is limited since it is estimated from the signal path power loss.  If you have two recent iOS devices you can try it out yourself between them with the air locate example.

Comment: Thanks i am going to implement this in my project incase if i get any doubts i will contact you back